# Get date for a specific day which is after today's date

Tags: php, date, mktime

If I have date like **22-11-2016(d-m-Y)** and the day is **Saturday** for whom I have to search the date and it would be **26-11-2016(d-m-Y)**. So How to get it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get next week day's date then might be this can help you.

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('next saturday'));
```

Or also you can use PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object as below.

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$date = new DateTime('22-11-2016');

// Modify the date it contains
$date->modify('next saturday');

// Output
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you going, using DateTime you could do this.

```
$date = new DateTime( '22-11-2016' );
$date = $date->modify( 'next saturday' );
echo $date->format( 'd-m-Y' );
```